# Robocopy from list.txt

Tags: windows, robocopy

I have a ton of user directories, that I need to move along with permissions to another location, the command I use on an individual basis is :

robocopy "\filer\home" "h:\UserHome" /E /SEC /Copy:DATSOU /log:c:\logfile.txt

Is there a way that robocopy can point to a list of directories in a test file, that need to be moved, instead of doing it one by one which is the way im currently doing.

Comment: What version of Windows

Answer (score 3):

Create a file named directories.txt:

```
C:\dir1
C:\dir2
C:\dir3
C:\dir4\subdir
```

Then write a Powershell script named RobocopyDirsFromList.ps1:

```
Foreach ($Directory In Get-Content .\directories.txt)
{
    robocopy "$Directory" "h:\UserHome" /E /SEC /Copy:DATSOU /log:c:\logfile.txt 
}
```

Note: I've not tested this, please test first.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work, tried a few different scenarios, the directories I put in as \\servername\folder\username but the script flashed up a command screen then disappeared. Didn't create a logfile either, im local admin on the server, and have all the permissions.

Comment: The above code is more of skeleton example. Immediate problem is I assume you need to specify both the source and target folders in the text file. That's tricky - a better solution would be to put the list in a CSV and then use the PowerShell Import-CSV command. Two columns. One for source and one for target. But as this post is 5 years old, probably not going into much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create folder list file

copy this script and save as BAT/CMD file:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (list.txt) do robocopy "%_source%\%%a" "%_dest%\%%a" /E /SEC /Copy:DATSOU /log:c:\logfile.txt
```